# c# - Cannot convert lambda expression to delegate type; but this works in List functions

Tags: c#, function, methods, delegates

Why is it that when I pass a lambda expression (i.e. p => p.Damage) in the predicate parameter in a custom method, as defined below:

```
public static void Sort(T[] input, int low, int high, Func<T, bool> predicate) { do_something() }
```

throws the "cannot convert lambda expression to delegate type" exception, while the exact same thing happens in the List class' functions, i.e.

```
intList = new List<int>() { 1000, 9102, 123, 41, 10, 52, 24, 8, 26 };
int i = intList.FirstOrDefault(b => b > 25);
```

Why does this not throw an error, while this does?

```
Sort(intList.ToArray(), 0, 9, i => i > 25);
```

The predicate argument passed in my function looks exactly the same as the predicate argument in the FirstOrDefalt function! Do I really need to explicitly state for my method that the lambda expression is a Func, or do I really need to create an anonymous delegate for something that I expect to work exactly the same? It doesn't make any sense to me, because the FirstOrDefault signature has absolutely zero indicative that it allows a Lambda Expression, all it expects is a Func delegate, and it's exactly the same as I'm doing.

Comment: I doubt that `p => p.Damage ` returns bool, and your predicate is definitely a `Func<T, bool>`, not `Func<T, int>` or something.

Comment: Can you post more of your code?

Comment: Are you getting an exception at runtime or a compilation error? Please add the full error message.

Comment: It is a good idea to post the error message - Error 1 A local variable named 'i' cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to 'i', which is already used in a 'parent or current' scope to denote something else. This error message is quite self-describing and has nothing to do with type inference. If you rename either the first i or i in lambda everything will compile fine.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This works:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main( string[] args )
        {
            var intList = new List<int> { 1000, 9102, 123, 41, 10, 52, 24, 8, 26 };
            intList.ToArray()
                   .Sort( 0, 100, x => x > 27 );
        }
    }

    public static class Ex
    {
        public static void Sort<T>( this T[] input, int low, int high, Func<T, bool> predicate )
        {
            input.ToList()
                 .ForEach( x => predicate( x ) );
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

This works because the defined predicates “predicate” represents a function taking an object of T as parameter and returning a Boolean value. And all I did was to create an anonymous function matching the defined predicate…

I can’t explain why or what didn’t work in Schalks code, because I don’t know his code…

**Edit 2** (add complete code sample):

If you are using the Sort(int index, int count, IComparer comparer) method of List you need an instance of IComparer to compare the list items. If you want to be able to specify the comparer as a lambda expression, you need a class implementing IComparer which internally uses a lambda expression to compare the items. (Or with .net 4.5 you can use [`Comparer<T>.Create` Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh737198.aspx) .)

Here is a full sample:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main( string[] args )
    {
        var idiots = new List<Idiot>
        {
            new Idiot { Weapons = new[] { new Weapon { Damage = 10 }, new Weapon { Damage = 20 } } },
            new Idiot { Weapons = new[] { new Weapon { Damage = 6 }, new Weapon { Damage = 100 } } },
            new Idiot { Weapons = new[] { new Weapon { Damage = 45 }, new Weapon { Damage = 12 } } },
            new Idiot { Weapons = new[] { new Weapon { Damage = 24 }, new Weapon { Damage = 5 } } },
        };

        foreach ( var i in idiots )
            i.Weapons.QuickSort( 0, i.Weapons.Count() - 1, ( a, b ) => a.Damage.CompareTo( b.Damage ) );

        //Solution using IEnumerable{T} extension methods
        idiots.ForEach( x => x.Weapons = x.Weapons.OrderBy( y => y.Damage ).ToArray() );
    }
}

public static class Ex
{
    public static void QuickSort<T>(this IEnumerable<T> input, int low, int high, Func<T, T, Int32> comparer)
    {
        input
            .ToList()
            .Sort( low, high, new FunctionalComparer<T>( comparer ) );
    }
}

public class FunctionalComparer<T> : IComparer<T>
{
    private readonly Func<T, T, Int32> comparer;

    public FunctionalComparer(Func<T, T, Int32> comparer)
    {
        this.comparer = comparer;
    }

    public Int32 Compare(T x, T y)
    {
        return comparer( x, y );
    }

    public static IComparer<T> Create(Func<T, T, Int32> comparer)
    {
        return new FunctionalComparer<T>( comparer );
    }
}

public class Idiot
{
    public Weapon[] Weapons { get; set; }
}

public class Weapon
{
    public Int32 Damage { get; set; }
}
```

FunctionalComparer implements IComparer and compares two objects based on a given lambda expression.
QuickSort creates an instance of FunctionalComparer (with the given expression) and uses this instance to sort the items.

But instead of writing all this code you could use the IEnumerable extension methods to do this.